# Ajax call for json request

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, request

Can I use Ajax call for this JSON request? I want to get some values from this request. And if I can what should I do?

My request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=test&cref=AIzaSyAreDhTh3IqaGPqC44t08sQF_qbSGzzA7Q&cx=010855067127206535986%3Aqdh_vhglb4u&fileType=jpg&filter=1&imgSize=medium&imgType=news&num=4&searchType=image&start=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: You should start here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Yes, you can. Here's a manual: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ You're welcome to come back if you get stuck with a problem you can't solve after searching for solutions!

Comment: I believe you're trying to get google search results, right? Use PHP's [Client URL Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to fetch search results. And yes, you can use ajax call for that.

Comment: Yes I need to get an image-link value from this request. But as I am newby in php and google-image-search-api I have no ideas what can I do with this request)

Answer (score 0):

You use AJAX to get any request, Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for all the available methods, but you'll want to use [jQuery.Ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

heres an example :

```
// There are a multitude of options that can passed in here
var req = $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: // ...Your Long URL ,
});

// use the returned promises
req.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});

// if it was unsuccessful
req.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

The Documentation is extensive, have a look and you should be able to get through this with relative ease.